# Mapping single-words to lists

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

*This is my entry for [mobile-friendly puzzles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7484/monthly-topic-challenge-12-mobile-friendly-puzzles).*

---

I am interested in eight single-words having a common theme. I wanted to create eight lists which map to those words. The mapping procedure is a secret.

---

List 1:

- If She Knew What She Wants
- Manic Monday
- Walk Like an Egyptian
- Walking Down Your Street

---

List 2:

- Into the Mirror Black
- Into the Mirror Live
- Refuge Denied
- The Year the Sun Died

---

List 3:

- Avesnes-sur-Helpe
- Cambrai
- Douai
- Valenciennes

---

List 4:

- Arepo
- Opera
- Rotas
- Sator

---

List 5:

- Cut the Strings
- Eve
- Galvany Street
- More!
- Movements
- The Sun & The Neon Light

---

List 6:

- Day in Day Out
- Paperfaces
- Yesterday Went Too Soon

---

I missed preparing remaining two lists. **Which two words map to those missing lists?**

Comment: I don't know how suitable this is for mobile-friendly puzzle tag because I have created more simple puzzles than this one. But the puzzle can ultimately be solved by just using your mobiles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The missing two groups map to ...

> ... **Interstellar** and **Oppenheimer**.

The lists ...

> ... are complete sets of things with one item missing and they map to that missing item.
>
>  1. **Following**: Singles from the album *[Different light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Different_Light)* by the Bangles.
>  2. **Inception**: *[Sanctuary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanctuary_(band))* albums.
>  3. **Dunkirk**: Subprefectures of the *[département du Nord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nord_(French_department))*
>  4. **Tenet**: words of a famous [acrostic word square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sator_Square).
>  5. **Memento**: *[Booka Shade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booka_Shade)* albums.
>  6. **Insomnia**: singles of Feeder's *[Yesterday Went Too Soon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yesterday_Went_Too_Soon)* album.

These are all ...

> ... single-word titles of **[Christopher Nolan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Nolan)** films. The missing titles are **[Interstellar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_(film))** and the recent **[Oppenheimer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppenheimer_(film))**. (The films of the Batman trilogy and *The Prestige* have titles of more than one word.)

I must confess that ...

> ... I solved it on a desktop computer. `:)`